# How to use Redis Cache to store the data in java spring boot application?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, redis, redis-cache

I have already a running instance of Redis Cache in AWS Account.
How can I use the redis instance using the redis instance Endpoint in my java code to store the data.

I don't have any idea how to start with Redis Cache in java.
Please help me out to resolve this.

Comment: Start with https://github.com/redis/jedis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `spring-data-redis` by including following dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>    
</dependency>
```

Then specify properties as below:

```
spring.redis.database=0
spring.redis.host="Specify URL"
spring.redis.port=6379
spring.redis.password=mypass
spring.redis.timeout=60000
```

Then using `RedisTemplate`

```
@Autowired
private RedisTemplate<Long, Book> redisTemplate;

public void save(Book book) {
    redisTemplate.opsForValue().set(book.getId(), book);
}

public Book findById(Long id) {
    return redisTemplate.opsForValue().get(id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @shrm.

Comment: I am trying this method which you given. In the application.properties what I have to fill in spring.redis.host="Specify URL", spring.redis.password=mypass. Which hostname and password I have to add here?

Comment: @Kakashi The property name should give you a hint.